# In Storybook theming for brandImage how to change logo height or width?

Tags: themes, png, height, width, storybook

Within Storybook's *manager.js* when changing the theme I've found the documentation where you can add a custom logo with:

```
import { create } from '@storybook/theming'
import logo from '../src/images/logo.png'

export default create({
  brandImage: logo,
})
```

However I've been unable to find a way to adjust the logo size of a PNG. From my research it seems the only way to adjust the size is to implement a `width` or `height` in the SVG:

*logo.svg*:

```
<svg width="100" height="40" viewBox="0 0 290.72 112.41" [...]
```

*maanger.js*:

```
import { create } from "@storybook/theming"
import logo from "../src/logo.svg"

export default create({
  brandImage: logo,
})
```

I'm unable to find a way in the docs ([params](https://storybooks.netlify.app/configurations/options-parameter/) or [themeing](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/theming)) if there is a way to set the `width` or `height` of a PNG.

### Research

- [Storybook change logo](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/13035)
- [Link to brandImage not working](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/9443)
- [Custom theme brand image not being displayed in the Sidebar](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/13313)
- [Storybook's styling overrides all](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/17533)

In Storybook is there a way when using a PNG for `brandImage` I can adjust the `width` or `height` without having to implement it as a SVG?

Answer (score 2):

I found a 'hacky' way of achieving this:

```
brandTitle: `<img src="/your-logo.png" width="10px" height="10px"/>`
```

Make sure your png file is inside the public folder in your root project.